# publishing a site in release mode using aspnet_compiler in batch file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, aspnet-compiler

i am trieng to create a batch task that will publish my site in release mode 
but with no luck...

my script for doing so is this:

```
aspnet_compiler -errorstack -nologo -fixednames -v / -p "C:\projects\mysite\COMPONENTS\sitefolder" -f -u  "C:\projects\publish-mysite"
```

my site has about 10 other projects in the solution. so i expect them to all be published in release mode. (the site refrence those projects)

please help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant lines from one of my build.bat files

```
rem set debug to false
sed -i 's/debug="true"/debug="false"/g' ../TZ/Web.config

"%VSDIR%\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" ..\TZ.sln /build Release
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler" -nologo -v TZ -p ..\TZ ..\compiled
```

Comment: and maybe the first line as well? :)

Comment: rem is a comment in a batch file.  sed is "Stream EDitor" it is a common unix command line tool, there are many versions for windows too.  All the sed line does is replace debug="true" with debug="false" in web.config.  Many tools could do the job, I am accustomed to sed.